# What does each color of damage number mean?

Tags: the-division

When you shoot enemy damage you deal is represented in a few colors (white, blue, red, golden, etc).

What does each of the colors mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there's only 4 different color damage.

- White - Normal damage when hitting an unarmored foe with a body shot.  This is damage done to their health.
- Red - Normal or Armor damage when hitting a foe with a head shot.  This is damage done to their health if they're unarmored, or to their armor if they're armored.
- Orange - Critical damage when hitting a foe (unarmored or armored) with a head or body shot.  You'll have a small chance at getting critical shots but other gear and abilities will increase this chance.  This is damage done to their health if they're unarmored, or to their armor if they're armored.
- Blue - Armor damage when hitting an armored foe with a body shot.  This is damage done to their armor indicated by the white bars above their health.  Dealing enough damage will destroy their armor.

Comment: I quite sure headshots on armored enemies are show in red and do bring down their armor too.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say that the red shots apply to both armored and unarmored.  But didn't make that distinction.

Comment: blue shots are more penetration hits. if you hit an enemy through an obstacle (car,wooden cupboard) then you get blue numbers, i guess it also accounts for shooting through their armor